# Прямая и обратная перестановка символов в строке по таблице замены

Tags: python

Есть таблица перестановок символов в строке (символов восемь). `table = [6, 8, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 1]`. И текст `text = 'qwertyui'`, перестановку делаю таким способом: `perm = ''.join(text[x - 1] for x in table)` и получаю выходную строку `yiwreutq`, т.е первый символ из строки text, становится шестым, второй - восьмым и т.д, т.е. из строки `qwertyui` получается строка `yiwreutq`.

Но вот с обратной перестановкой возникли сложности, придумал только такой вариант: `txt = ''.join([i for sub in sorted(zip(perm, table), key=lambda t: t[1]) for i in sub[0]])`, хотя кажется, что есть вариант намного проще.  Как можно еще реализовать обратную перестановку, т.е. чтобы из `yiwreutq` снова получить `qwertyui`?

Спасибо.

Comment: table.reverse() не поможет?

Comment: @Taarim Нет, конечно же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
''.join([new_str[table.index(i+1)] for i in range(len(table))])
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать таблицу соостветствия:

```
In [90]: tab = list(zip(map(lambda x: x-1, table), range(len(table))))

In [91]: tab
Out[91]: [(5, 0), (7, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3), (2, 4), (6, 5), (4, 6), (0, 7)]

In [92]: back = ''.join(perm[b] for _,b in sorted(tab))

In [93]: back
Out[93]: 'qwertyui'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
txt = table[:]
for k,i in enumerate(table):
    txt[i-1]=text[k]
txt = ''.join(txt)
```